# Nhibernate Dynamic Search With

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm encountering an issue while working with NHibernate queries and joins. I have a scenario where I need to retrieve `Holding` entities based on specific conditions related to `Insurance` and `Depot` associations. However, when I attempt to combine these conditions using separate queries and joins, I'm getting unexpected results or crashes.
Interestingly, both separate queries work fine individually.

```
Session.QueryOver<Holding>(() => holdingAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(h => h.Id).In(holdings)
    .Where(h => h.Insurance != null || h.Depot != null)
    .Left.JoinAlias(h => h.Insurance, () => insuranceAliasFilter)
    .Left.JoinAlias(h => h.Depot, () => depotAliasFilter)
    .Where((h) => h.Depot == null && insuranceAliasFilter.InsuranceCompany != null && insuranceAliasFilter.InsuranceCompany.Id == insuranceCompanyId
                || h.Insurance == null && depotAliasFilter.InsuranceCompany != null && depotAliasFilter.InsuranceCompany.Id == insuranceCompanyId)

     // test output
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => depotAliasFilter.InsuranceCompany.Id)
        .Select(() => insuranceAliasFilter.InsuranceCompany.Id))
    .Take(10).List<object>()
```

Some sugestions?
Thx.

I expect to retrieve a list of Holding entities that match either the Insurance condition or the Depot condition

Comment: Just because two SQL queries work well independently doesn't mean they'll work if you just inject one inside the other. The `Where` with the null checks could be reduced to a single `query=query.Where(h=>h.Depot==null)` or `query=query.Where(h=>h.Insureance==null)`. The other conditions are evaluated on the client-side only and don't have to be sent to the server. Same with the JOINs - they seem to be a way to generate an `insurance.ID in (@id1, @id2,...)` clause

Comment: Each operator in the question's code returns a query object. To generate queries based on conditions all you need to do is evaluate the conditions and then append the necessary clauses. You don't have to chain everything together and you definitely shouldn't send client-side conditions to the server. This only results in more complex and slower queries